# Unity build using custom C# script from command line without editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, build, cicd

I want to make pipeline for github to build unity project. I'm using flutter-widget plugin, which defines custom C# scripts, which builds unity. So i need from command line call method for example: Class.buildToAndroid.

The main problem is, that it can be done using Unity.exe editor - but i don't think it's good to install whole unity editor in pipeline (for example in Github actions). Is there a way to install only Unity CLI, or part responsible for building?

I made it to work:
`"%UNITY_PATH%" -batchmode -quit -projectPath "%PROJECT_PATH%" -executeMethod FlutterUnityIntegration.Editor.Build.DoBuildAndroidLibraryRelease -logFile build.log`
But i need for it whole Unity Editor - too large.

Comment: You might want to rather use [Game-CI](https://github.com/game-ci) and in specific [unity-builder](https://github.com/game-ci/unity-builder) or [unity-actions (for testing)](https://github.com/game-ci/unity-actions)!!! It basically offers certain docker images and uses these so no long Unity installation - just the docker image boot time and done